# A regex to test if all words are title-case

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex to validate the following to be true:

```
This Is A Cat
```

However, to evaluate the following to be false:

```
This is a cat
```

Or this to be false too:

```
This Is A cat (Note the 'c' is not upper case in Cat)
```

I'm trying in JavaScript, thought the following should work:

```
/(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s*\b)+/
```

Here is my logic:

1. Start at a word boundary
2. Match an uppercase character
3. Match zero or more lowercase characters
4. Match zero or more spaces
5. Match a word boundary
6. Repeat the above one or more times

What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: Can you post your javascript code?

Comment: I believe your regex is simply matching any string that contains one or more Title Case words. Adding a `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end should fix this.

Comment: `/^\s*(?:\s*[A-Z][a-z]*\s*\b)+\s*$/` [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/j7McBE/1)

Comment: @ETHproductions, you should make it an answer instead of a comment as you are right.

Comment: Down-vote, really?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know if a string matches the condition, and don't care where it fails, you can check for either a lower case letter at the start of the string, or a lower case letter which follows a space:

```js
var str = 'This Is A Cat';
if (str.match(/\b[a-z]/)) {
  console.log('Not Title Case');
}

var str2 = 'This is A Cat';
if (str2.match(/\b[a-z]/)) {
   console.log('Example 2 Is Not Title Case');
}

var str3 = 'this Is A Cat';
if (str3.match(/\b[a-z]/)) {
   console.log('Example 3 Is Not Title Case');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with my thinking?

You're finding a sequence of title-cased words, but that won't pick up cases where there are non-title-cased words.

You can test if the entire input is **not** title case with the simple regexp:

```js
const tests = ['This Is A Cat', 'This is a cat', 'This Is A cat'];

// Is there any occurrence of a word break followed by lower case?
const re = /\b[a-z]/;

tests.forEach(test => console.log(test, "is not title case:", re.test(test)));
```

If you really want to check that the input **is** title case, then you'll need to match the string from beginning to end, as mentioned in a comment (i.e., "anchor" the regex):

```js
const tests = ['This Is A Cat', 'This is a cat', 'This Is A cat'];

// Is the entire string a sequence of an upper case letter,
// followed by other letters and then spaces?
const re = /^\s*([A-Z]\w*\s*)*$/;

tests.forEach(test => console.log(test, "is title case:", re.test(test)));
```

#### What is title case?

Strictly speaking, however, articles, conjunctions, and prepositions are not upper-cased unless they start the title. Therefore, a better test would be:

```
const re = /^\s*[A-Z]\w*\s*(a|an|the|and|but|or|on|in|with|([A-Z]\w*)\s*)*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guessing is that you have forgotten to include the global match sign `g` at the end.

> **`g`** finds all matches rather than stopping after the first match

Try to do it this way:

```
/(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s*\b)+/g
```

Comment: This will find all contiguous sequences of title-cased words, but how will it let you know that there were non-title-cased words?